# Android Emulator first startup time

Tags: android, android-emulator

We have latest android SDK setup with eclipse. We have android 4.x images (with and without google apis). When a new such AVD is created, the first run takes too long and some times it just keeps booting.

Examining logcat there are 3 things that take a lot of time.

1. DexOpt
2. resource loading
3. Collecting certs

I guess 1 and 3 are reasonable additions to startup time as one-time processes.

However, I don't understand why the startup takes arbitrary long time and sometimes just keeps booting.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the AVD uses only one core of your computer to simulate "real device" data processing, however you are not bound to use the regular AVD as you can use [genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator - it's faster and also has a plugin for eclipse.

you can also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow),[here](https://www.infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/articles/is-your-android-emulator-just-too-slow) and [here](http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/development/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator/) for further information

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am just interested in running and AVD as it keeps booting with display of android animation.

Comment: than genymotion is your answer.. =)